# input formatter directive

Tags: javascript, widget, angularjs, directive

Please take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/007design/VahqD/).

I'm trying to create a "widget" that will allow the user to select either a `$` or `%` sign and format a text field accordingly.  I've got it working, sort of, but it's not updating the underlying model properly.

Can someone please point out what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

This occur because a bug(at least I think) with isolated scopes, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VahqD/14/) working without an isolated scope

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a filter?

Something along these lines?

http://jsfiddle.net/ganarajpr/bbKFg/1/